# How to show regular price for odd Items in the cart and sale price for even items in the cart?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

All my products in the shop are on a sale so they have a regular price and sale price.
When customer adds product to the cart, I want to show product sale price for even items in the cart 2.4,6 etc and  regular price for odd items in the cart- 1,3,5 etc.

All the items are on a sale, so odd items need to show regular price instead of sale price)

Have added the below code to - main-cart-items.liquid but it did not update the price on cart.

```
{% assign itemIndex = 0 %}

{% for item in cart.items %}
{% assign itemIndex = itemIndex | plus: 1 %}
<tr class="cart-item" id="CartItem-{{ itemIndex }}">
<!-- Existing code for image, details, and other columns -->

<td class="cart-item__totals right medium-hide large-up-hide">
  <div class="loading-overlay hidden">
    <!-- Existing code for loading overlay -->
  </div>
  <div class="cart-item__price-wrapper">
    {% assign isEven = itemIndex | minus: 1 | times: -1 %}
    {% if isEven %}
      {%- if item.original_line_price != item.final_line_price -%}
        <dl class="cart-item__discounted-prices">
          <!-- Existing code for discounted prices -->
        </dl>
      {%- else -%}
        <span class="price price--end">
          {{ item.final_line_price | money }}
        </span>
      {%- endif -%}
    {% else %}
      <span class="price price--end">
        {{ item.original_line_price | money }}
      </span>
    {% endif %}

    {%- if item.variant.available and item.unit_price_measurement -%}
      <div class="unit-price caption">
        <!-- Existing code for unit price -->
      </div>
    {%- endif -%}
  </div>
</td>

<!-- Remaining code for quantity, remove button, and error -->
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Can anyone please help how can I achieve this?

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

To find out if a number is even or odd, you want to divide by two.  If there is a remainder, then it's even, otherwise it's odd.

To find the remainder, use the `modulo` filter.

Replace

```
{% assign isEven = itemIndex | minus: 1 | times: -1 %}
```

With

```
{% assign remainder = itemIndex | modulo: 2 %}
{%  if remainder == 0 %}
  {% assign isEven = true %}
{% else %}  
  {% assign isEven = false %}
{%  endif %}
```

Comment: I updated the above code, but it doesn't give the output as required. All the products still show the sale price. If we can just get the regular price of the product instead of the sale price on the cart first then we can work with even odd logic to get the output.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that '0' is not a falsy value in liquid.  Changed the isEven calculation, and it seems to work on my site.